# Micronaut - Configuration placeholder in @Endpoint id ignores custom value

Tags: micronaut

I'm defining my endpoint like so:

```
@Endpoint(id = '${jupyter.endpoint.path:jupyter/kernel}')
public class KernelEndpoint {

    @Write
    public Map start (request) {
        return [
            "message": "Kernel start request received!"
        ]
    }

}
```

When I run the application without passing any value for `jupyter.endpoint.path`, the endpoint `id` is correctly set to the default value `jupyter/kernel`.

However, if I pass in a custom value like so:

```
def endpointPath = "command/jupyter/start-kernel"
def serverUrl = "https://localhost:8080"
// create application context
ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContext.run([
    'jupyter.endpoint.path': endpointPath,
    'jupyter.server-url': serverUrl
], Environment.TEST)
```

the endpoint `id` will ignore the custom value and still use the default value:

```
 assert applicationContext
    .getBeanDefinition(KernelEndpoint)
    .getAnnotation(Endpoint)
    .stringValue("id")
    .get() == endpointPath
```

I couldn't find anything in the docs that indicate one way or another whether this should work. Does anyone know if what I am attempting is supposed to work, and if so, why it isn't for me?